# The asympotic distribution of a sequence of estimators

Tags: asymptotics

Here's the question

Consider a sequence of estimators $X_{i}=X_{1},X_{2},...,X_{N}$ for $i=1,...,N$. 
Each estimator is resulting from a sample $j=1,...,n$. 
 For each estimator $X_{i}$ the asymptotic normality is satisfied, as $n \rightarrow \infty$  with $N(0,X_{i}^2)$
and $σ^2=X_{i}^2$. Can we say that the asymptotic normality of the sequence $X_{i}$ is satisfied?

Comment: "asymptotic normality is satisfactory" means "asymptotic normality is satisfied/verified" ? ALso, $\rightarrow N(0,X_{i}^2)$ makes no sense, you meant $\rightarrow N(0,\sigma_{i}^2)$ ? Also what is $X$ ?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I made some changes to my question.